# Should I remove already installed php package before recompliling from source

Tags: php, ubuntu, pthreads

I would like to recomplile php from source with option --enable-maintainer-zts for install pthreads then. I do something like:

```
apt-get source php5
sudo apt-get build-dep php5
```

then edit rules and add --enable-maintainer-zts option and finally do

```
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -b
```

but at the finish after passing > 10k tests I do not get recompiled php version.
What is wrong? Should I remove all php installations first?